# 301 Redirect url with query string?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I like to do the following redirection:

*domain.de/?file=team* ––> *domain.de/team.html*

To do this I try the following rewriting (that is'nt working):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^file=team$
RewriteRule ^/$ /team.html [L,R=301]
```

How can I do this  301 redirection?

Answer (score 0):

Got **the solution** by my self:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^file=team$
RewriteRule ^$ /team.html? [L,R=301]
```

*domain.de/?file=team ––> domain.de/team.html*

If you see my question above I've made the following two mistakes:

**1. Mistake: Missing Question Mark**

If you remove the question mark then the query_string will not be removed:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /team.html [L,R=301]
```

*domain.de/?file=team ––> domain.de/team.html?file=team*

Just a further hint by the way the command RedirectMatch is not able to remove query_strings.

**2. Mistake: Wrong Rewrite Path**

```
 RewriteRule ^\$ ... does not match doamin.de/?file=team
 RewriteRule ^$ ... matches
```

Comment: The `^/$` regex doesn't work because the prefix (leading slash) is stripped off of the path when processing rules in a per-directory context, like within a `<Directory>` container. By extension, all rules in htaccess files are per-directory because they are applied within the context of the directory the htaccess file is in.

Comment: Your comment irritates me because I did'nt wrote `^/$`  ... I wrote `^\$`

Comment: Your question says: "`RewriteRule ^/$ /team.html [L,R=301]`"